# How to automate the installation of a LAMP server with Administration Panel Webmin/Virtualmin

Tags: server, system-installation, debian, automation

How can I automate the process server installation on Linux Ubuntu or Debian GNU / Linux?

Is there a script to automate the installation and configuration of a LAMP server with the Administration Panel Webmin / virtualmin (GPL version)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested to automate the installation of a Linux Ubuntu server process (all versions) or Debian GNU / Linux, is available to the community a bash script, that i wrote, that allows:

- Automatically Update packages on the first installation;
- Automating the hostname configuration;
- Automate HOST settings, resolv.conf;
- Automatic detection of the main server IP;
- Installation and configuration of the control panel Webmin / virtualmin;

This script is not meant to be nothing more than a help in automation of installation procedures of a LAMP server + Webmin / virtualmin (GPL Version).

Usage:

- Send the magicbrain-osi_1.0.sh script script to the server;
- Chmod +755 magicbrain-osi_1.0.sh the script;
- Run the script and follow the instuctions installation;
- After the package update, the server will restart automatically;
- Access again to the server and run the magicbrain-osi_1.0.sh;
- Follow the instructions of the phase 2 installation;

[**Download magicbrain-osi_1.0.sh**](http://magicbrain.pt/magicbrain-osi_1.0.sh.tar.gz)

This installation automation script is on the GNU / GPL v3 and can be used and modified freely.